# Is there any way to increase the speed of the blades (air coming out) of my fan?

Tags: everyday-life, rotation, fan

[image]

Don't worry, my ceiling fan do not have any mechanical problem(if i will not mention it most of you will say repair your fan) it's just a part of home experiment.

Once looking at the blades of my fan I supposed can I increase the speed of blades (and hence amount of air coming from it) just by applying some physics??

The  interesting point came  when one of my friend said yes you can just bend the blades of your fan. I tried it but it didn't worked so for the final suggestion, I supposed to come here.

Someone of you may say that this question is not clear so forget all,the question you have to answer is **Can I increase speed of blades of my fan just by applying some physics**.

I m not asking about any formula or procedure to measuring the speed of blades, i m just asking how can i increase the speed of blades

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fan Speed Formula](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/184647/)

Comment: @JohnRennie how can you relate two question which seprately ask about speed calculation formula and speed increasing phenomena.

Comment: @THELONEWOLF. Actually, you can slightly increase the speed of the blades by wrapping them in a smooth aerodynamic envelope that is symmetric. Then the blades will move much less air around, and will rotate slightly faster. I think this is not what you want - you really want to increase the speed of the air, right? Or maybe the [Volumetric flow rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volumetric_flow_rate)?

Comment: I can't get you@user27542 as i don't know what aerodynamic envelope is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no aerodynamic method of speeding up the blades.

The speed of the fan blades would be tied to the speed of the motor, so to speed them up you would need to speed up the motor. You could achieve that using a pulley system, like a V-belt with a larger wheel on the motor and a smaller one attached to the fan, or some kind of gears, or by increasing the frequency of the electricity supply to an alternating current motor.